# Storyboards VS xib's use concept

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a custom `UIViewController` class that I want to show when a `UITableViewCell` is pressed, so I get a callback when a particular cell has been pressed.

My project is a navigation based application and i have created the `ViewController` that I want to present in the `StoryBoard` but it have no segue connected to it because it should be called from a dynamic `UITableViewCell`.

The `ViewController` also set as the class that Subclassing it.

So now I am trying to do something like :

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[AddAccountsViewController alloc]init] animated:YES];
```

It does push but all I see is black screen. with an `XIB` I could just create it separately but then I lose the 4 inch screen auto fit behavior which I dont want.

How can I mange this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you can do this two ways.

The first way is kind of what you're doing but you're not quite getting it right...

**Option 1**

In the storyboard property pane. Select the `AddAccountsViewController` and set the storyboard identifier to "AddAccountsViewController";

```
AddAccountsViewController *controller = [self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddAccountsViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

**Option 2**

This is the easiest option.

Create a segue in the story board between the main view controller and the `AddAccountsViewController`. CTRL drag from the yellow circle of the main controller.

Give the segue an identifier like "AddAccountSegue".

Then in code...

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AddAccountSegue" sender:nil];
```

**NOTE**

There are other ways of doing this but these two are the simplest to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a prototype in the storyboard for the dynamically created tableview cell?

If so you can ctrl-drag to the destination view controller from the cell prototype to create a segue.

Comment: Oh totally, but you can still have a prototype for the cell in a dynamic table view.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Do you mean you are creating it in code?

Answer (score 1):

You can ctrl+Drag to make segue from destination to source view controller like this. And then after selecting tableViewCell in you .m file, you can write this line of code to define segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"source" sender:nil];
```

Good Luck!![image]